# Wordpress post category out of the loop but in the rss feed

Tags: wordpress, rss

in my website, done with wordpress, I have this function for excluding some category from appearing in homepage:

```
function excludeCat($query) {
if ( $query->is_home ) {
$query->set('cat', '-14, -64, -68, -22, -15');
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'excludeCat');
```

But they are excluded also from the RSS feed. There is a way to exclude them from the homepage but include them in RSS Feed?

I use custom RSS created with these functions

```
function customRSS(){
add_feed('ppfeed', 'customRSSFunc');
}
function customRSSFunc(){
get_template_part('rss', 'ppfeed');
}
```

And [this](http://pastebin.com/SrLmjV4t) is the rss-ppfeed.php file

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to exclude the feed (**edit** page templates also) page from your if condition

```
function excludeCat($query)
{
    if ($query->is_home() && !is_page()) {
        $query->set('cat', '-14, -64, -68, -22, -15');
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'excludeCat');
```

**Edit**

Add this before the line number '5' IE before the line with $postCount = 10; , in rss-ppfeed.php

```
remove_filter('pre_get_posts','excludeCat');
```

Comment: That is weird , if you are using a free theme , can you please name it ?

Comment: It is not free, it is called Mediablog and my website is http://www.primapaginaonline.it

Comment: Just to be sure , you have placed the code in your themes functions.php , right ?